# How to read a file line by line in crystal language?

Tags: crystal-lang

Hi I want to read a file line by line with crystal language, but I don't know how can I do that.

I read crystal documentation, but I couldn't find my answer.

It's my code:

```
system("ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ > Fox.txt")
file = File.read("Fox.txt")
system("sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/\'#{file}\' >> Fox_done.txt")
```

Comment: [`File#each_line`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.0.0/File.html#each_line(filename:Path%7CString,encoding=nil,invalid=nil,chomp=true,&)-class-method) or [`File#read_lines`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.0.0/File.html#read_lines(filename:Path%7CString,encoding=nil,invalid=nil,chomp=true):Array(String)-class-method) should work

Answer (score 4):

To read a file line by line, you can use [File#each_line](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/File.html#each_line(filename:Path%7CString,encoding=nil,invalid=nil,chomp=true,&)-class-method):

```
File.each_line("/path/to/input.txt") do |line|
  puts line
end
```

If the file is small and you want to load all lines in memory, you can also use [File#read_lines](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/File.html#read_lines(filename:Path%7CString,encoding=nil,invalid=nil,chomp=true):Array(String)-class-method):

```
File.read_lines("/path/to/input.txt") # returns a Array(String)
```